# Extjs4 add an empty option in a combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a combobox in ExtJS4 with this initial config

```
        xtype: 'combobox',
        name: 'myCombo',
        store: 'MyStore',
        editable: false,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'id',
        emptyText: 'Select an Option'
```

I don't know if there is an easy way to tell the combo to add an option so the user can deselect the combo (first he select an option and then he want to not select anything... so he wants to return to "Select an Option")

I solved this before by adding an extra option to the fetched data so I can simulate to have the "Select an Option" as a valid option in the combo but I think there should be a better way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need any new design or graphics or any complex extensions. ExtJS has is all out of the box.

You should be able to use this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.field.ClearCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.clearcombo',

    trigger2Cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;


        me.addEvents(
            /**
            * @event beforeclear
            *
            * @param {FilterCombo} FilterCombo The filtercombo that triggered the event
            */
            'beforeclear',
            /**
            * @event beforeclear
            *
            * @param {FilterCombo} FilterCombo The filtercombo that triggered the event
            */
            'clear'
        );

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.on('specialkey', this.onSpecialKeyDown, me);
        me.on('select', function (me, rec) {
            me.onShowClearTrigger(true); 
        }, me);
        me.on('afterrender', function () { me.onShowClearTrigger(false); }, me);
    },

    /**
    * @private onSpecialKeyDown
    * eventhandler for special keys
    */
    onSpecialKeyDown: function (obj, e, opt) {
        if ( e.getKey() == e.ESC )
        {
            this.clear();
        }
    },

    onShowClearTrigger: function (show) {
        var me = this;

        if (show) {
            me.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    el.setWidth(el.originWidth, false);
                    el.setVisible(true);
                    me.active = true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            me.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    el.originWidth = el.getWidth();
                    el.setWidth(0, false);
                    el.setVisible(false);
                    me.active = false;
                }
            });
        }
        // ToDo -> Version specific methods
        if (Ext.lastRegisteredVersion.shortVersion > 407) {
            me.updateLayout();
        } else {
            me.updateEditState();
        }
    },

    /**
    * @override onTrigger2Click
    * eventhandler
    */
    onTrigger2Click: function (args) {
        this.clear();
    },

    /**
    * @private clear
    * clears the current search
    */
    clear: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.fireEvent('beforeclear', me);
        me.clearValue();
        me.onShowClearTrigger(false);
        me.fireEvent('clear', me);
    }
});
```

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/)**

And a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/1/)** without a default combo.

**Note that both examples don't require any new graphic or style**

Comment: just a side note: the line --> show = ( Ext.isBoolean( show ) ) ? show : false;    <--- may be substituted with:  --> !!show <-- (which yields a truthy boolean.

Comment: @dbrin Absolutely right. But this one is quite old code and I am not even sure if this line is from me. Anyway, I fixed it.

Comment: What is onShowClearTrigger trying to accomplish? Looks like it hides the clear trigger once the combo's cleared. That seems to leave an ugly hole in my UI.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Yeah I know this. It's ugly but based on your version of ExtJS the framework will react different when hiding a element. In your case it seems, that you need to adjust the width in another way or don't do it all all. Or maybe you need to call a different update method after hiding/showing a element. It really depends on your version of ExtJS

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no better way of doing this. Although others may have a hack to do what you do by means of a plugin.

If I'm perfectly honest, no selection option in comboboxes is somewhat of a user interface paradox - users are required to select 'no selection'. A blank option is not very clear - looks a bit like a bug.

From a user interface perspective I think the preferred solution to this scenario is to have a button next to the combobox saying 'clear selection' (or just one with an X icon). Once you manage to put a button there, you can just call `clearValue()`.

Comment: Yeah that could be a solution, but the problem is that I don't control the design team. So I need to find a way