# show blank record in dropdown in extjs

Tags: extjs

I dropdown list in my extjs application, where data loads via Json. If only one record is present dropshows single record by default. Instead of this I want user to click on dropdown and select that record. So by default user can see empty text.

Here is my code.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                itemId:'dsUnitPanel',
                border:0,
                items:[UnitGrid,{
                xtype:'combobox',
                tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="x-boundlist-item" >{name} [{freeSize} GB Free] </div></tpl>',
                style:'margin:10px;',
                fieldLabel: 'Group(*)',
                editable:false,
                bodyStyle:'padding-left:10px;',
                store: dsGroupStore,
                valueField:'name',
                displayField:'name',
                multiSelect: false,
                name: 'txtMode',
                id:'dsGroupId',
                queryMode: 'local',
                triggerAction: 'all',
                emptyText:'Select Group'
```

I want to show empty text always by default, so that user can click and select the value if it single also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This same question is always coming back again and again. The point here is you need a way to allow users to select **nothing**, however they select the blank option which is not **nothing** but a valid option instead.

I strongly recommend avoid that way. If you need to provide a way to deselect the combo, you can use a trigger for that.

[image]

Please, take a look at the answer for the following question:
[Extjs4 add an empty option in a combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830537/extjs4-add-an-empty-option-in-a-combobox/13835193#13835193)

And also check the examples in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

On your store, add an empty record, like this:

```
dsgroupStore.add( { name: '' } );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had also found one answer which always show empty text: "Select Group", even in case of single entry. Just need to put forceSelection: true;

Answer (score 0):

I had also found one answer which always show empty text: "Select Group", even in case of single entry. Just need to put

```
forceSelection: true;
```