# Enter new values in ComboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am trying to develop a combobox that allows the user to enter value which get lookuped and if it is missing in the list it get viualize as a new value (I'd thought about a image left to the field) and in additon causes the field to be bound to another property of the model where it is assigned to.

In addition the user should be able to clear the combo value.

I started by using a [provided class from this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830537/extjs4-add-an-empty-option-in-a-combobox/13835193#13835193) and extended it with the required settings. I managed to prevent a issue which causes the 'x' trigger to hide continious, but I couldn't manage the difference between userinput - selection - set - clear (set value by form)

Here is a snippet from what I've got so far

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.field.InputCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.inputcombo',

    trigger2Cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',

    newRecordFieldname: null, // the name if this value is new
    originName: null, 

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.addEvents(
            /**
            * @event beforeclear
            * @param {Combo} Combo The combo that triggered the event
            */
            'beforeclear',
            /**
            * @event beforeclear
            * @param {Combo} Combo The combo that triggered the event
            */
            'clear'
        );

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.on('specialkey', this.onSpecialKeyDown, me);
        me.on('afterrender', function () { 
            me.onShowClearTrigger(false); 
        }, me);

        this.on('change', function() {
            this.createdRecord(this);
        });
        this.on('select', function() {
            this.onSetExisting(this);
        });
    },

    createdRecord: function(ref) {
        ref.newRecord = true;
        ref.selectedRecord = false;
        ref.originName = ref.name;
        ref.name = ref.newRecordFieldname;
        ref.style = 'background:url(../resources/themes/images/default/dd/drop-add.gif) no-repeat left center;'; // does not work
    },

    setExisting: function(ref) {
        ref.newRecord = false;
        ref.selectedRecord = true;
        ref.style = '';
        ref.name = ref.originName;
    },

    /**
        * @private onSpecialKeyDown
        * eventhandler for special keys
        */
    onSpecialKeyDown: function (obj, e, opt) {
        if ( e.getKey() == e.ESC ) {
            this.clear();
        }
    },

    onShowClearTrigger: function (show) {
        var me = this;

        if (show) {
            me.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    el.setWidth(el.originWidth, false);
                    el.setVisible(true);
                    me.active = true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            me.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    el.originWidth = el.getWidth();
                    if (el.originWidth !== 0) { // prevent double hide
                        el.setWidth(0, false);
                        el.setVisible(false);
                        me.active = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        me.updateLayout();
    },

    /* lines remoced. see linked answer */
});
```

What I haven't get managed to get working (and the point where I need help) is to show a image for a new record and that the field behaves in the same manner regardless if I first enter something and clear or set a value, select a value and so on. By know the field behaves quiete different or does not work at all.

In additon it should be compatible to the upcoming 4.2 release. Dunno if this important to mention.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you put a fiddle up of the current progress that you have, and also perhaps provide a screenshot of what you'd like to see happen, visually.

Comment: I would like to have a better understanding of the expected behavior.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for here.